# Passing a derivative through a function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a function $H=f(T,P)$ at which I evaluate $H_1$ at $(T_1,P_1)$.  Now I change $P$ to $P_2$, keeping $H$ the same so I can calculate the new value $T_2$.  So $f(T_1,P_1)=f(T_2,P_2)$ and I know $T_1,P_1,P_2$ which gives me $T_2$.

Now I have an extra complexity where $T_1$ is a function of another variable, $Q$, so $T_1=g(Q)$.  I know $\cfrac{dT_1}{dQ}$, and also $\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial T}$ and $\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial P}$

I need to find $\cfrac{dT_2}{dQ}$.

Comment: I try to understand what I read, I can't. What do you mean by "inverting a function"?

Comment: I don't understand what you are writing, but maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: @DonAntonio: If have rephrased the first sentence.

Comment: @amsmath: no that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Can the P-values depend on Q?

Comment: No $P$ and $Q$ are independent variables.  Actually so was $T$ until I found out today it depends on Q!

Comment: Not following you here.

Comment: Made a small mistake.  If you can simplify amsmath's answer below, it is what I intended

Comment: ok I did a bit of simplifying, trust I got it right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $h(x) = f(x,P_2)$. Then $T_2(Q) = h^{-1}(f(T_1(Q),P_1))$. So, using the chain rule several times,
\begin{align}
T_2'(Q)
&= (h^{-1})'(f(T_1(Q),P_1))\cdot f'(T_1(Q),P_1)\binom{T_1'(Q)}0\\
&= \frac 1{h'(h^{-1}(f(T_1(Q),P_1)))}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}(T_1(Q),P_1)T_1'(Q)\\
&= \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}(T_1(Q),P_1)T_1'(Q)}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}(h^{-1}(f(T_1(Q),P_1)),P_2)}\\
&= \cfrac{T_1'(Q).\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial T}(T_1(Q),P_1)}{\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial T}( T_2(Q),P_2)}
\end{align}

Comment: Seems to me the last row can be simplified to: $\cfrac{T_1'(Q).\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial T}(T_1(Q),P_1)}{\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial T}( T_2(Q),P_2)}$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Confirmed correct against numerical derivatives with a test example.  Thanks!